# highlight shortest path on plot of graph

Tags: r, shortest-path, igraph

I am trying to find a way to highlight some shortest paths on my graph. 
I am trying to automate the use the output of get.shortest.paths into the path= function of E() but the data structure seems wrong. See below:

```
###################################################################
g <- graph.ring(10,directed=TRUE)               
plot(g)
ShortPth <- get.shortest.paths(g, 8, 2)    # List of path 8->2
ShortPth
E(g)$color <- "SkyBlue2"
E(g)$width <- 1
E(g, path=ShortPth)$color <- "red" 

### setting edges by path= is failing !!!!!!!!!!
plot(g)
```

#############################################################

any help would be greatly appreciated....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you just missed a few brackets.  The `path` argument wants a numeric vector, but `ShortPth` is a list.  So, you can supply a vector by typing `ShortPth[[1]]`
Try the following:

```
E(g, path=ShortPth[[1]])$color <- "red"
plot(g)
```

#### Update:

As pointed out in the comment by jcarlos, the above solution throws an error with `igraph_1.0.1`:

> Error in as.igraph.vs(graph, path) :    (list) object cannot be
>   coerced to type 'double'

The documentation says the `path` argument should be `A list of vertices, to select edges along a path.`  Passing in a list throws an error, though.  Any of the following are working at the moment with `igraph_1.0.1`:

```
E(g, path=ShortPth$vpath[[1]])$color <- "red"
E(g, path=unlist(ShortPth$vpath))$color <- "red"
E(g, path=unlist(ShortPth[[1]]))$color <- "red"

ShortPth$vpath[[1]]  # class "igraph.vs"
# + 5/10 vertices:
# [1]  8  9 10  1  2
unlist(ShortPth$vpath)
# [1]  8  9 10  1  2
```

Comment: For lists you need `[[` to get a single element. `[` creates sublists.

Comment: in the current igraph version I only got after addressing vpath list E(g, path=ShortPth$vpath[[1]])$color <- "red"

Comment: @jcarlos Thanks for pointing that out.  Edited and looking into it further.

Answer (score 0):

You can also easily do this using mathematica using the function ShortestPathFunction[].